I keep getting Unused expression without side effects when adding more than one assertion
So I used to be able to run multiple assertions however now I keep getting the warning "Unused expression without side effects". Every assertion on its own however passes the test just fine. How would I get around this?
val result = borrowingService.transform(input)

val overview = result.openAccounts.head
overview.accountType shouldBe "CreditCard"

overview.totalBalance shouldBe SummaryMonetaryAmount(4000, 2, "GBP")
overview.totalLimit shouldBe SummaryMonetaryAmount(12000, 2, "GBP")
overview.totalUtilisation shouldBe Some(33)`

I don't want to return the entire response because I want to test for these specific fields

You could define overview outside the test, and then wrap each assertion in different test cases. There are some test frameworks such as scalatest that let you group test and nest things inside like WordSpec?

This is probably related to a new linter in the compiler to check for unused pure expressions.
In practice, this can catch a lot of bugs like:
def foo(): Int =
  computeValue() // Unused value, probably a mistake.
  10

However, as with most linters, it can't really know the full semantics of everything. In this case, ScalaTest assertions look like pure values but are really side-effecting. Thus, discarding them makes sense.
The easiest fix if you don't want to disable the whole linter, is just to configure it to ignore these:
// Disable Wnonunit-statement warnings related to ScalaTest Assertion.
Test / scalacOptions += "-Wconf:cat=other-pure-statement&msg=org.scalatest.Assertion:s",

Add that in the right place of your build.sbt
